# What should be an 'expiration date' column type when in some cases it doesn't have any value? (blank? null? 0000-00-00?)

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes, mysql-5.7, sqldatetime

I have a table stating which items I am using in my main menu:

model | display_name | sub_menu | active

MYSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `main_menu` (
  `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'name of the model',
  `display_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sub_menu` enum('Fruits','Vegtables','Grains','Breads','Snacks','Sweets') DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

example:

```
model   | display_name  | sub_menu  | active
---------------------------------------------
potato  | Potato        | Vegtables | 0
apple   | Apple         | Fruits    | 1
pumpkin | Pumpkin       | Vegtables | 1
```

- I want to add an expiration date to it (*"exp_date"*).
- Not all rows have an expiration date.

What should be the type of `exp_date`? Obviously "Date".. but in cases that there is no exp_date for a certain row, what is considered a "good practice"? Inserting `NULL`? inserting `0000-00-0`?

```
model   | display_name  | sub_menu  | active    | exp_date
--------------------------------------------------------------
potato  | Potato        | Vegtables | 0         | NULL
apple   | Apple         | Fruits    | 1         | NULL
pumpkin | Pumpkin       | Vegtables | 1         | 2019-03-01
```

Using MySQL 5.7 and might migrate to the new 8 version. I just  want to make sure I'm doing this properly. I remember (not sure from where) that date types and date values in an issue and there is a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with using `NULL` as a placeholder when the expiration date be not known.  Consider as an example that you want to find all records which have not yet expired.  Treating `NULL` as not having yet expired, we can write the following query:

```
SELECT model, display_name, sub_menu, active, exp_date
FROM main_menu
WHERE exp_date > NOW() OR exp_date IS NULL;
```

Comment: Ok, and if one day I decide to set a NULLed cell to a date, If I decide to set it back to NULL, will this be a problem? (result any errors?)

Comment: NULLs are great to show a lack of data, for instance in cases where you do not know the expiration date of an item.  However NULLs can be problematic if you index the column,

Comment: I can't answer because I don't know exactly what you have in mind.  A MySQL datetime column can hold either `NULL` or a valid datetime value.

Comment: @DaveStokes Why would `NULL` values pose a problem any more than some other value?  Unless perhaps if the bulk of the column be `NULL`, in which case any index might not help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just want to be sure this is a proper way to do it

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, if the majority or a large number of the rows are NULL it will make indexes less beneficial.

Comment: Just use `NULL`.  When you have a million rows and _if_ you have issues, come back with a new Question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NULL` if you don't know the exp_date yet and use `9999-12-31` (max supported value for date) if the row does not expire.

Comment: That could be the `DEFAULT`, and using that lets you leave off the `OR .. IS NULL`.